# Maximize Form from Minimized State not working

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, messagebox, windowstate

When I try to Maximize a Form when it is in a Minimized state,  (I am using Windows Form)
It will not open. Can't figure why.

Here is an example of what I'm doing:

```
Button_X_Click(args, Events e)
{
  Form1.ActiveForm.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;

  DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show
  (
  this, 
  "Would you like to open Form?",
  "Title",
  MessageBoxButtons.YesNo
  )

  if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
  {
    Form1.ActiveForm.WindowState =
           FormWindowState.Maximized;
    MessageBox.Show("Done"); //For Testing
  }
```

Somehow, it does not open my Form.
It does show me the "Done" MessageBox.

Could use some help here ;)

Comment: Try adding a `.Show()` call after you maximize it.

Comment: where did you write the above code?

Comment: Within my form1 class

Comment: I tried Form1.ActiveForm.Show(); 
it gave me a blank form like it has not been initialized..

Comment: did you check. which form is active form?

Comment: How do i check?
checking on ActiveForm gives me null

Comment: A minimized window cannot be an active window.  You'll need to write smarter code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a reference to the form you are trying to manipulate.
I am expecting to see something like:

```
    form1.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

If this code is on the current form you are designing, then I am expecting to see something like:

```
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

A bit more context would be helpful.

Comment: guess you were right, Form1.ActiveForm = null.
but i can only add ref to Form1.ActiveForm or Form.ActiveForm
both are null at minimized state

Comment: The Form1 object being null is another issue. If you add full code of what you are trying to achieve, we can help you more effectively.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway this will work for you:

```
void Button_X_Click(object args, Events e) {
   Form f = Form1.ActiveForm;
   Form1.ActiveForm.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
   DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show( this,  "Would you like to open Form?",
                                     "Title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo );
   if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes) {
     f.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
     MessageBox.Show("Done"); //For Testing
   }
}
```

**NOTE**: The arguments of your `Button_X_Click` have something wrong, I just corrected it a little without caring too much about what `Events` is, in fact I think you mean `EventArgs`.

Comment: Indeed, i just created an Example of what i was doing ;)

Comment: @user2982172 what do you mean? is this answer helpful? If it is, you should consider accepting it.